how convert to array properly with special character in string
i want to split string to array,but if the string contain é,the split method not work
var string = "JonBenét";
var arrays = string.split("");

why arrays  like this ?

Array(9) [ "J", "o", "n", "B", "e", "n", "e", "́", "t" ]

i want convert like this,any suggestion thanks very much
Array(8) [ "J", "o", "n", "B", "e", "n", "é", "t" ]

i try Array.string(string),but it still convert
Array(9) [ "J", "o", "n", "B", "e", "n", "e", "́", "t" ]


Note that this string - "JonBenét" - contains a different (but identical looking) accented e that will split properly.

use the Intl.Segmenter JS API and set the granularity to grapheme to include special chars like "è" and such
